# How to retrieve string value of text view and again set calculated double to that text view in android?

Tags: android, gridview, textview, android-custom-view, charsequence

my project contains the grid view in which i created the custom view. Custom view had minus button, text view and plus button. My intention is like that, when i press on minus or plus button, the value of text view get changes according to some point. Please tell me how to implement that.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can get event of item from gridview and do as you wish .using onitem click listener of gridview

Answer (score 0):

```
String number = mTextView.getText()
int numberInt = Integer.parseInt(number);
```

IN plus button onClickListener

```
numberInt++
```

IN minus button onClickListener

```
numberInt--
```

and final

```
mTextView.setText(""+numberInt);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView mCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.count);
Button plus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus);
Button minus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minus);
plus.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
minus.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

private final View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
     case R.id.minus:
      mCount.setText(String.valueOf(Double.valueOf(mCount.getText().toString()) - 1));
      return;
     case R.id.plus:
      mCount.setText(String.valueOf(Double.valueOf(mCount.getText().toString()) + 1));
      return;
     default:
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set OnClickListener on button inside your gridView adapter, like this:

```
 button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String data = mTextView.getText().toString();
            double number = Double.parseDouble( data );

            number++;    //if you want to increase it by 1
            //or
            number += someValue;   //if you want to increase it by some value
            mTextView.settext(String.valueOf( number ));
        }
    } );
```

similarly you can set click listener on another button to subtract the value, just replce

```
number++;   
//or
number += someValue;
```

with

```
number--;    
//or
number -= someValue;
```

Comment: i added that custom view in grid View. so every view cell contains that custom view. My problem is, i want to fetch the value of particular view cell on which plus or minus get press

Comment: set click listener inside your getView method of adapter

`public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
        }
        Button button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item);

        //set click OnClickListener here
        /*here you don't need to manually handle gridView item positions 
       here.*/
        return convertView;
    }`

Comment: its works.. now i want to calculate the sum of all grid view cells values collectively.

Comment: you can do it in your activity class like this:

    `for(int i=0; i<myGridView.getChildCount(); i++) {
    TextView child = (TextView)mGridView.getChildAt(i);
    int sum += Integer.parseInt(child.getText().toString());
}`

Note: sometimes a GridView's child is another ViewGroup, so you may need to loop through it's children.